# Why is the voltage across the capacitor unbound?

Tags: capacitor

Consider:

[image]

Why does this circuit represent an unstable system? That is, the voltage across the capacitor is increasing with respect to time.

If this is the case, **what is the energy stored in the capacitor**?

Comment: Constant current means I=dQ/dt  a constant rising storage of charge

Comment: real constant current sources never go that high, so in the real world we rely on that ceiling to limit cap voltage (along with real methods)

Comment: True infinitely compliant current sources are rare in practice - luckily, because you couldn't rely on the ceiling to stop the *capacitor* :)

Comment: Sooner or later something will give.  Either the capacitor will break down or the current source will reach its max voltage output.  Only in theory can things go on forever.

Comment: Infinitely compliant voltage sources are rare in practice as well. The difference is we far more frequently pretend the voltage ones are. Don't confuse a difference in what you're used to modeling as a difference in reality. Look at a 1.5 volt 'batteries' discharge curve some time. You'll find it doesn't behave as typically modeled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand what is going on here, let's first make sure we understand two things in a well-defined way:

A [capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) stores charge on its plates. As it does, this difference in charge forms a potential difference (a voltage) between the plates. The ratio between the amount of charge on the plates (or in other words, in the capacitor) is given by the [capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance):

$$ C = \frac{Q}{V}$$

Where \$C\$ is the capacitance in [F] Farad, \$Q\$ is the charge in [C] Coulomb and \$V\$ is the voltage in [V] Volt.

We will also need to understand [Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current). Current is the (net) amount of charge that passes a certain cross section of the wire in a given amount of time. In other words, the current describes the flowrate of charge. In equations:

$$ I = \frac{Q}{t} $$

Where \$I\$ is the current in [A] Ampere (not amp-age or amperage! Those are historical terms), \$Q\$ is again the charge in Coulomb, and \$t\$ is the time in [s] seconds.

Now, with all this math behind us, what is going on here?

A current source will output a certain amount of current. This means that it is "pushing" a certain amount of charge out of it's "exit" terminal (the one the arrow points to) and sucking the same amount of charge into it's "entrance" terminal. This current flows into our capacitor. In other words, a constant amount of charge is continuously being pushed into the capacitor. 
If we write the charge in the capacitor as a function of time, we can see from our definition of current:
$$Q(t) = I \cdot t $$
Let's plug that into the voltage equation from the definition of the capacitor:
$$V(t) = \frac{Q(t)}{C} = \frac{I\cdot t}{C} = \frac{I}{C}\cdot t$$
In other words, the voltage on the capacitor is a function of time, increasing linearly with time! This is what you are observing: as time progresses, more and more charge is being pushed into the capacitor, creating more and more potential difference.

How much [energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy) is stored? We know that energy is work (=power) over time, or:
$$E = P \cdot t = V_{\text{avg}} \cdot I \cdot t$$

The trick here is that the voltage is not constant. We can solve this by filling in our equation for voltage we found earlier. Not that since the voltage is ramping up linearly, the average voltage is just half of the current voltage:

$$V_{\text{avg}} = \frac{V(t)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{I\cdot t}{C}$$

$$E = V_{\text{avg}} \cdot I \cdot t =  \frac{I\cdot t}{2C} \cdot I \cdot t = \frac{I^2 \cdot t^2}{2C}$$

NOTE: This is all assuming the current is constant. If it is not, we have to resort to an integral, and we can write that

$$Q(t) = \int_{t_{\text{start}}}^{t_{\text{end}}} I(t) dt$$ 
and 
$$V(t) = \frac{Q(t)}{C} = \frac{\int_{t_{\text{start}}}^{t_{\text{end}}} I(t) dt}{C}$$

The energy can now be calculated with

$$E = \int_{t_{\text{start}}}^{t_{\text{end}}} V(t) I(t) dt$$

Also note that in practice this will not be possible with "regular" components, as the voltages required will pretty much destroy any component hobbyists have access to.

Comment: Very nice and clean explanation!

Answer (score 5):

It's you yourself who has drawn a system where new charge is pushed into a capacitor at a constant rate 2 millicoulomb per second regardless how high is the accumulated voltage.  In practice there is allways some limit such as insulation breakdown or the maximum available source voltage, but in computer programs the only limit is the maximum available number.

This is how capacitors work. At constant charging current the voltage increases with rate =current/capacitance. In your case the growth rate is 200 volts/second.

There is a growing electric field between the plates that stores the energy. Your system seems to have reached voltage 33230 V at the taken snapshot. The stored energy in the capacitor was 0.5 * C* U^2 Inserting the snapshot voltage gives 5521 joules or equally 5521 watt-seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose one has a perfect spring whose force increases at a rate of 1 newton per centimeter of stretching.  One fastens one end of the spring to an immovable point and starts moving the other end away at a rate of 1 centimeter per second.  If the spring never fails, and one never stops pulling on it, what's going to happen to the force?

In practice, a spring would likely fail if something kept pulling it for too long.  If the spring didn't fail, the amount of power required to keep the end of the spring moving at a uniform rate would grow until it exceeded the power available.

In the electrical circuit such as you showed, the same situations would apply.  Either the capacitor would fail, or the voltage would exceed the capabilities of the constant-current supply.  In a sense, the voltage is equivalent to force trying to feed power back through the supply; the higher the voltage gets, the harder it is for the supply to overcome that push so as to push additional power into the cap.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what capacitors do. They charge up with a time constant to the voltage placed across them. Since your circuit has no voltage specified, the simulation just keeps pumping charge onto the plates. Where would you expect the voltage to level off? 10 V? 35 V?

The circuit does not provide the simulator with enough information, so-to-speak. It needs to either have a circuit voltage defined, or it needs to know the point (voltage) at which the capacitor breaks down/fails.

Comment: The source used is a current source(2mA). As the red arrow show, the voltage across the capacitor has reached 33.23kV. Here the voltage across the capacitor keep on increasing w.r.t to time. This is not a practical circuit, I know that it's just to play with the Mathematical model of the capacitor.

Comment: @TinkerBell agreed. Does this comment differ from my answer? We're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor is like a water tank and a current source is like an open water valve, as long as the valve is opened the tank (capacitor) will charge until it reaches it's max charge (litters for the tank as volts for the capacitor). In real life the capacitor will break when it gets to it's voltage rating, bit in simulation the capacitor is ideal, so it's a water tank with infinite depth